# Setting the current active tab in a bootstrap menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following bootstrap menu (pills) defined in a partial:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here are some sample routes:

```
  get 'institute/:institute_id/students' => 'students#index'   , as: 'students_of_institute'
  get 'students/:student_id'             => 'students#show'
```

I have referenced this partial in various views. How do I dynamically change the current active tab?

Comment: You need to match on the current path or route. If you can provide an example of your defined routes it may make it easier to decide which way to go. Ideally you'd wanna match on a programmatically defined route - matching on a path is a bit more hacky

Comment: Make sure you initialize the Bootstrap tab using JS. Demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJgbqE?editors=1010

Comment: This gem might help you - https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to

Comment: I added a couple of my rotues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to check the current path and if it matches your link's add an `active` class to your `li`.

An easy way would be to compare `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`.

For example:

```
# GET /posts
params[:controller]     => "posts"
params[:action]         => "index"
```

Here is a "dirty" example. It's better to move it out to some helper:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'students' && params[:action] == 'index' %>"><%= link_to 'Students', students_path %></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure if I followed you. If possible, could you please provide some sample code based on the routes I have. Into which file does this code go?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to @Uzbekjon's solution is to use the `current_page?` helper method. The first argument is the controller, the second (optional) is the action.

Since your navigation links will be top-level links, you will usually not need to specify the action. That way, you will still have an active pill for sub-pages in the same controller.

E.g:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page? controller: :students %>">
    <%= link_to 'Students', students_path %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think this is slightly more elegant.

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it too. Thanks!

Comment: This solution seems to work only on the index page of the controller.  How do you get it to work on all pages within the controller's scope?

Comment: @Wes I rarely use Rails nowadays, but please leave an example of what you mean. I imagine if you looked up the API for the `current_page?` method you'll be able to explore your options http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F